# Перенаправления на поддомен opencart 2

Tags: php, .htaccess

Не совсем понимаю как можно сделать.

Есть форма регистрации там есть поле subdomen в которое записывается названия поддомена.

Названия субдомена.

`$sub = $this->customer->getSubdomen()`

Я хотел сделать что бы ко всем ссылкам дописывалось  http://my-site.com/my-account&sub=test есть файл seo_url.php побывал там добавить но что не получилось. 
В настройках .htaccess что бы получилось типа  http://test.my-site.com/my-account 
в настройках хостинга есть возможность добавлять Субдомен (*) 
Возможно так реализовать ?